# Combine array of arrays to single array with elements with JQuery

Tags: jquery, arrays, syntax

Probably a simple Jquery syntax question, yet I failed to do it:

I have an array of arrays, like

```
 n = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]]
```

But I'd like to change it to

```
 m = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9]
```

So I think in other words **I want to go from an array of arrays to an array of single 'elements'**.

How would I do that?

I tried `$.merge(n)` but it didn't work as I wanted.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need to use jQuery for everything.

```
var n = [[1,2,3], [4,5,6], [7,8,9]];

var result = [];
for (i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
    result = result.concat(n[i]);
}
```